# How to restore all deleted GitHub branches?

Tags: git, github

I was trying to add all my commits from a branch on an old repository to a new branch on a new repository and I accidentally deleted all the branches on the new repository. How can I restore all of these deleted branches? Do I have to restore them individually?

These are the commands that caused the issue:

```
git clone --mirror <url_of_old_repo>
cd <name_of_old_repo>
git remote add new-origin <url_of_new_repo>
git push new-origin --mirror
```

Comment: Please show the actual commands you gave to Git. Don't describe code, show it.

Comment: I will update the question now

Comment: You made a `mirror` clone. A `mirror` clone is a `bare` clone. A `bare` has no visible local branches and is not expected to have any. If that isn't what you wanted, why did you do that?

Comment: It was part of a solution for adding commits from one branch to another branch in another repo. I found this on stackoverflow. @matt

Comment: Note that `git push --mirror` automatically includes `--prune`. If the "new repo" over on GitHub was empty, this was OK. If not, it was not. (This sort of thing is why blindly following a recipe found somewhere, without carefully understanding each part of it first, can be a bad idea.)

Comment: The new repo was not empty. All its branches were deleted. Thankfully there were no current pull requests. Everything had already been merged to master.

Comment: My master branch is protected so everything is still there and the commits are still there.

Answer (score 0):

(Note: this answer is not tightly focused because your question is not as focused as it might be.  I had to *guess* what you did.)

Branches—or more precisely, branch *names*—just remember one specific commit, in any given repository.  As long as those *commits* are still in the repository, you can re-create the branch *names*.

The tricky part is that you have to remember the hash IDs of those commits.  Given that hash IDs of commits look random,<sup>1</sup> where will you get those hash IDs?  The best place would be from a *clone* of that repository: a clone will have, stored in it, the name-and-hash-ID pairings.

- If you don't have a clone of the repository, you may be out of luck.  Cloning the existing GitHub repository will copy only those commits that you can *find in* that repository, which—without the branch names—is few or perhaps none of them.

  If it's a paid GitHub account, or the GitHub staff are helpful enough, *they* might be able to recover the name-to-hash-ID pairings from some alternate or backup copy they have of your repository.  To find out, contact GitHub support.
- If you *do* have a clone of the repository, see below.

Now, whenever you clone some existing Git repository, you do it by running:

```
git clone <url> [destination-directory]
```

This operation creates a new, empty repository in the destination directory you specified, or—if you didn't specify one—in a directory derived from looking at the URL you gave `git clone`.  For instance the URL `ssh://git@github.com/user/repo.git` turns into the destination directory name `repo`.  Then, inside this new empty repository (let's assume it's in `repo`), your Git:

- saves the URL under the name `origin`;
- calls up the Git over at GitHub and connects that other Git up to the other repository;
- has them—the other Git—list out all their *branch names* (and tag names);
- turns those *branch names* into *remote-tracking names*;
- gets *from* that other Git all the *commits* found by using their branch names (and tag names);
- stores those commits in your new `repo` repository, using those *remote-tracking names* to locate the most recent commits; and
- last, creates one *branch* name in your copy.

This means the branch names in your copy—your clone—are not particularly useful here, but the *remote-tracking names* **are**: for every *branch* name they had, you have one *remote-tracking name*, holding the same hash ID.

Their branch name `xyz` becomes your remote-tracking name `origin/xyz`; their branch name `fred` becomes your remote-tracking name `origin/fred`; their branch name `super/cali/fragi/listic/expi/ali/docious` becomes your `origin/super/cali/fragi/listic/expi/ali/docious`, and so on.  So, what you need to do is:

- for each remote-tracking name:

  - send any commits from your clone to their clone by using the remote-tracking name in your repository to find the commits;
  - ask them to create, in their repository, a *branch name* derived by taking `origin/` away from that remote-tracking name, to remember the last commit as found by the remote-tracking name in your repository.

This is easy enough to do with `git for-each-ref`, though there are a few tricky parts.  Here's a tiny shell script to do it, which makes one assumption: that `HEAD` is the only symbolic name that has to be discarded here:

```sh
git for-each-ref "--format=%(refname:short):%(refname:lstrip=3)" refs/remotes/origin |
grep -v ":HEAD$" | xargs echo git push origin
```

I broke this up into two lines for posting purposes; it should work this way in sh / bash, but you can join it all up into a single line.  Take out the word `echo` to make it actually run `git push`, instead of just showing what it *would* do.

Note that this requires a not-too-out-of-date Git version.  If your Git does not have the `:lstrip` modifier for `git for-each-ref`, you need a slightly different script.

---

<sup>1</sup>They're not actually *random*, but they *are* immensely *unpredictable*, so for our purposes here they might as well be random.

Comment: Hey, I remember forking the project to a third repo, in case something like this happened. In this third repo I found all the branches, about 80-100 commits are missing. Are there any quick commands to us to add these branch names from my third repo (which contains majority of the branches that were deleted) to the **new repo** I described in my original post? @torek

Comment: Also, will the solution you have provided restore only the commits?

Comment: You'll get back those commits, as found by those branch names. Remember that `git push <url> <commit>:<name>` means: *call up the Git at the URL, tell them that they need the commit chain at ends at the given commit, send them any commits they need for this chain, and then ask that they create or update the given name to remember that commit.*

Comment: Given that you have now mentioned that you are using the GitHub protected-branch feature to make the Git at <url> say "no" to any request that they set their `master`, note that this sequence of "give them the commits and ask that they set their name" will fail for `master`. You might want to filter that one out or change its name a bit. If you use the `echo` variant, you'll get a Git command that you can modify, to send from `origin/master` to `master.xyzzy` or whatever, for instance.

Comment: If it is blocked by master, could I just push it to another branch and then merge with my master branch? @torek

Comment: That's ... what I just suggested above: leave the `echo` in, so that you get a command you *could* run. Then *modify that command*, exactly as I already described.

Comment: Is there anyway to restore all the tags as well using a similar solution to the one provided?

Comment: Yes: use `git push --tags` from the clone. Tags, unlike branch names, don't get renamed, so you don't have to rename them back. Make sure there's no overlap between the tag names in the old and new repositories first though.